# Python input being cleared when another thread calls print

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, input, printing, pycharm

I have the following code, which lets me print and receive keyboard input at the same time:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def InpThread():
    while True:
        response = input("Type in here\r\n")
        print("Response is " + response)

tinp = Thread(target=InpThread)
tinp.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Printing")
```

I've stripped this down to a simple case, my case has other stuff but the problem is reproducible for me with this example.
Last week, I had no problems with the return of input() giving me all characters entered till that point. Now, it appears every call of print() in the other thread wipes all characters away, so that mostly I am left with an empty input, unless I time it right and am very fast.

```
Printing
aPrinting
b
Response is b
Type in here
Printing
```

I am using Python interpreter 3.5.2.

I cannot see any change in my code over the last week, all I can think of is that Windows has updated, or perhaps the python module.

How can I keep all input and not have it wiped by a call to print()?

Comment: are you talking about the print 'Printing'? Because, without the last while loop, the code seems to work fine!

Comment: Where it says "Response is b" it should say "Response is ab", because I pressed both a and b, but a was wiped by the print.
I've now realised it may be worth mentioning that I'm running this from within PyCharm, and a separate console window appears to perhaps yield different results.

Comment: I've now found it definitely has something to do with the PyCharm console.

Comment: May be, I tried with python console and it worked as expected!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `lock` on the print function.

Check [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207592/1683017). It creates a lock object and uses it later to print.